# How can I access the internal variable of a method in Java junit?

Tags: java, random, junit, mockito, integration-testing

I have a function in which a random number is generated as shown below

```
public void method(){
     int number = random();
     // continue
}
```

My question is how can I access this variable without mocking random method?

I need this variable for my test scenarios.

Comment: you can't, nor should you.

Comment: You can't. If you **really** need this variable you should turn it into an instance variable with appropriate getters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do if you really need this is refactor your code:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyClass {
 private<Supplier<Integer>> final random;
 
 public void method() {
  int number = random.get();
  // ...
 }
}
```

You can then inject it in the test

```
public class MyTest {
 @Test
 public void testMethod() {
  Supplier<Integer> supplier = () -> 3;
  MyClass sut = new MyClass(supplier);
  sut.method(); // random in method will be 3
 }
}
```

However, I assume you're doing something like this

```
public void method() {
 int random = random.get(),
 service.call(random);
}
```

then you can use an ArgumentCaptor.

```
@Test
public void testMethod() {
 Service service = mock(Service.class);
 MyClass sut = new MyClass(service);
 myClass.method();
 ArgumentCaptor<Integer> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);
 verify(service).call(captor.capture());
 // captor.value() now contains the value you're looking for
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, and you should not.

If you want to make it reusable, You should extract it to a `public static` variable within the class and reuse it elsewhere.

Also, if it's random, why do you need to have it reused? Just randomize it in test, too, or provide the `int` value as a method parameter, which kind of makes the most sense.

Comment: This is actually a very simplified description of my problem
In fact, the variable I want is not an int type, and I need its value for an integration test